# Basic Calculus counterexample

Tags: calculus

We know that if we have two real differentiable functions $\;f,g\;$ **on an interval** $\;I\subset \Bbb R\;$ s.t. $\;h'(x)=g'(x)\;\;\forall\,x\in I\;$ , we then get that $\;f(x)=g(x)+C\;$ on $\;I\;$ , $\;C=$ a constant, and from here we get, under the same assumptions, that with a twice differentiable function $\;f\;$ **on an interval** $\;I\;$

$$(1)\;\;f''(x)=a=\text{ a constant}\;\implies\;\exists\,\text{constants}\;\;b,c\;\;s.t.\;\;f(x)=\frac a2x^2+bx+c\;\;(2)$$

The above is pretty simple, but my problem now is to find a counterexample as simple as possible to the last claim above **if $\;I\;$ is not an interval** , meaning: a function $\;f\;$ differentiable twice and fulfilling (1) does not *necessarily* have the form (2) *if we don't assume $\;I\;$ is an interval* .

By simple I mean that this is Calculus I and any argument about connectedness or the like must be avoided if possible.

Thanks (Yes, I know: "Don't thank anyone!", but my mom's education kicks in here...)

Comment: If $I$ is the disjoint union of two intervals, then the constants $b$ and $c$ can differ on the two separate intervals (it. $f$ would be a "piece-wise quadratic")

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @PrahladVaidyanathan .+1

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan. But *not an interval* does not imply that you are dealing with the union of two disjoint intervals. So you could still have cases where $I$ is *not* an interval and form (2) is *necessary*.

Comment: Yes, but that is a much more involved question. The OP just asked for a counterexample!

Comment: How about the step function, which illustrates the first order case as well?

Comment: Thanks @drhab. I think Prahlad's counterexample can work fine to the question "show that if $\;I\;$ is not an interval then the above isn't true".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$f: \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R} $
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x>0 \\ -1 & x<0 \end{cases}
$$